# TSQL/SQL - Loop

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I am New to TSQL/SQL and i want to learn 'While Loops' in TSQL/SQL. IS there any Good  sites/books which can help improve my knowledge regarding 'Loops'.  Your input is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Avoid looping constructs in SQL and start thinking about set operations. Looping constructs are _expensive_ in SQL.

Comment: Thanks Oded, will keep that mind. Any idea regarding study material.

Comment: read the SSMS online help or just google `WHILE Transact-SQL`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a book - just read up on the [cursor functionality in T-SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx). There are code examples demonstrating looping. Like Oded says, looping is an imperative construct whereas SQL is a declarative language - looping in SQL is "doing it wrong" although the functionality is there for when you really need to be "doing it now".

Comment: If you are forced to loop in SQL, use a WHILE at least. NEVER use a cursor! Cursors will ultimately kill your performance. I repeat, do NOT use cursors.

Comment: Thanks for the Tip. Will read about both the topics and see why one is better than other.

Comment: I disagree with the comment that CURSORs will kill your performance only in that in some cases a CURSOR is the only way to go. For example doing set based operations by creating a dynamic SQL string that is generated from the operation of the CURSOR. NEVER is a very strong word.

Answer (score 1):

A SQL loop is pretty much the same as any other programming loop, as in, it runs until the given condition is no longer met. 
However, as Oded mentioned, SQL is a SET based language primarily, and is weaker as a procedural language. Please refer to [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2009/03/30/procedural-versus-set-based-sql.aspx) article for more information on the difference of set versus procedural, especially when it comes to SQL.

So, in conclusion, look for ways to rewrite any loop queries so that they are more SET based on a group of data at one time. If you cannot, then maybe it is more of a problem for code, and not SQL

A good solution that can usually avoid while loops and has been implemented pretty well by the SQL teams is below. Hopefully, this can help you if you cannot go to code and are still looking for an efficient solution in SQL

- [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx), or Common Table Expressions are extremely powerful, especially if you need something like [recursion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the Input. I was thinking about scenarios, for example, like for all the rows in a table do something. Cases like this might need Loops.

Comment: I have updated my answer to point you in the direction of CTE's. They are often a more efficient way to do what you might have normally done in loops. Often, they are combined with ROW_NUMBER() and PARTITION. However, I would re-iterate about trying to think in SET logic, and if you cannot create a solution that way (especially if you are referring about rows "doing" things), then use code

Comment: CTE might do the trick. Will read about it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

MSDN is usually the best online documentation for anything in the Microsoft technology stack.

[MSDN - While (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178642.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for the link.Agree, MSDN seems a good place for information.